# ProgressBar on Windows Phone 7 is not showing

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to show a ProgressBar in my Windows Phone 7 app when the app is fetching data.

Here is my XAML:

```
        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="headlines">             
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="220" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Name="refresh" Margin="320,-630,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="75" Width="75" BorderThickness="0" Click="refresh_Click">
                    <Button.Foreground>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/DataCollector.Tone;component/Resources/refresh-pressed.png" />
                    </Button.Foreground>
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/DataCollector.Tone;component/Resources/refresh.png" />
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock Text="from heraldsun" Margin="12,-30,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></TextBlock>
                <ProgressBar 
                    Margin="0,-40,0,0"
                    x:Name="progressBar"
                    IsIndeterminate="true"
                    Visibility="Visible" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                <ListBox Name="headlines" Margin="0,10,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Tones}" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,17,0,17">
                                <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Height="75" Width="100" Margin="12,10,9,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                <!--<Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FFE5001b" Margin="12,0,9,0"/>-->
                                <StackPanel Width="311">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>                   
                <!--Double line list with image placeholder and text wrapping-->
            </Grid>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

Here is the back end code:

```
        // Load data for the ViewModel Items
        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
            {
                App.ViewModel.LoadData();
                progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                headlines.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make sure the ProgressBar is big enough (in terms of height).

Comment: If I now look at the problem this way. The XAML code is as follow:

<toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar 
                        x:Name="performanceProgressBar" 
                        Margin="0,-40,0,0" 
                        IsIndeterminate="true" 
                        Visibility="{Binding ShowProgressBar}" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

and the code behind is as follows:

private bool ShowProgressBar
{
    get { return !App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded; }
}

The progress bar does not disappear after the data has been loaded, i.e. ShowProgressBar is false.

Comment: @SalmanJamal You can edit your post. It's more readable than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the PerformanceProgressBar from the [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291).

It runs on the compositor thread, so it won't block with UI things.

Answer (score 0):

In following code:

```
if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
{
    App.ViewModel.LoadData();
    progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    headlines.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

If `App.ViewModel.LoadData()` is a synchronous method, thant may be keeping your UI from updating.

Try putting entire `MainPage_Loaded` code into a seperate method and call it asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your most recent comment correctly, the problem you have now is that the value of the visible is initialy true, because the data is loading, and then the binding never occurs again when the data is loaded. I would recommend hooking up to an event (and making it on the data model if need be)

```
App.ViewModel.OnDataLoaded += (s, e) => performanceProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
```